# Running tests involves background theads performing db operations hungs when running inside a Junit Suite

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, junit

**Background**
We are building a product using Spring / Hibernate (JPA based) / Restful API from Jersey. During project build phase , we are running Integration tests to make sure that all the Restful API's are behaving as expected.

In recent past, we have migrated to use two entity managers which is used for another sub-product merged with this. Things become started messing up from there onwards

We are having background threads which performs few operations asynchronously. Initially we faced issues for these background jobs to get hold of their respective Entity manager factory. But we somewhat solved the issue using  **OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.**

As part of integration tests run , we will be bringing up Jetty server and deploy the application there for testing.

**Current problem Scenario**
When running those tests involves the background processing  **individually,** they are running fine.
As we had multiple tests in place , Starting and stopping Jetty server resulted in long duration of tests run.

So we have grouped all tests inside a test suite and configured this suite inside the surefire-plugin.

**The tests which have worked individually started hanging under running inside a suite.** 
Test Suite setup is given below.

```
@BeforeClass
public static void setUp()
{
// Startup of jetty server happens here
}

@AfterClass
public static void tearDown()
{
// Stopping of jetty server happens here
}
```

In individual tests, we will complete the background process in @BeforeClass and performing the data cleanup activities in @Afterclass method.

I am litte weird about how the tests works fine as individual starts causing issues when running inside a test suite

Any configuration / ideas would be much appreciated.

Comment: are your tests hitting the jetty server - any logs?

Comment: Yes. They are hitting the server correctly...

INFO: Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 41869 ms
Feb 26, 2015 2:20:30 PM org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler initialize
INFO: Initiating Jersey application, version Jersey: 2.5.1 2014-01-02 13:43:00...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to happen due to connections are not returned from connection pool after being used. Once we started increasing the maximum.connection.pool.size the issue stops occurring.

Thanks for all your comments

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that it is one of these things:

1. You are not mocking something correctly, and you are changing the state of the data you are using in tests
2. You are doing some operations on your database that the test is not able to "repair" (e.g. drop or rename table)
3. You are using some static variables somewhere and these are building you a state machine that you don't expect/want

If you can say how the tests are failing, that might help

Comment: There is no error as such. It simply hungs there for some back ground processing to finish. But it is waiting infinitely running inside a test suite